# passing array of values from view to controller using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I have a form in my view page.it contains 5 text boxes,one search button.while the user enters values in textbox(Entering all fields are not mandatory)and click on the search button,the values I have to store it in an array and pass it to the controller and depending upon the search results i have to display the results of those searched records.

I am able to store the searched values in an array,now i want how to pass this array to the controller and how to access these values in the controller.

Comment: Point the form action into one action of your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,how to pass these array of values from view to controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax. If jQuery is an option you could write something like this

```
$(form).submit(function()
{
    var ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controller/Action",
        data: JSON.stringify(_yourArrayObject),
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.Result);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

as Jose referred , your request may look like this :

```
 $("#submit").click(function () {
        var searchData = new Array();
        $(".search-input").each(function () {
            searchData.push($(this).attr('value'));
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Index",
            data: {"searchData"  : searchData},
            success: function (data) {
                // do something on success
            },
            traditional: true,
            dataType: "json"
        });
        return false;
    });
```

and your controller action could be :

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix="searchData")] List<string> searchData)
    {
        return Index();
    }
```

and your form have to have markup like this:

```
<form id="myform">
       <input type="text" class='search-input' />
       <input type="text" class='search-input' />
       <input type="text" class='search-input' />
       <input type="text" class='search-input' />
       <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I have implemented in this way ,I used foreach loop in my controller for entered value is null or not.when i enter one value in the text box and click on the search button ,at the foreach button it is throwing NullReference Exception.